mock.patch object extending into non-decorated methods?
I have the following code:
def get_mocked_contract_event():
    event = {#stuff}
    return event


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def context():
    yield

#works as expected
@mock.patch("ticketfactory.TicketFactory", autospec = True)
def test_success_ticket(mock_ticket_factory, context):

    return_ticket_mock = mock.Mock()
    soap_mock = mock.Mock()

    mock_ticket_factory.getTicket.return_value = return_ticket_mock
    return_ticket_mock.buildRequest.return_value = soap_mock

    from call_ticket_lambda import lambda_handler

    response = lambda_handler(str(get_mocked_contract_event()), context)

    assert response == "success string"

#fails on AssertionError, ticket is of type mock?
def test_contract_ticket_soap():

    from call_ticket_lambda import TicketFactory

    ticket = TicketFactory.getTicket("CONTRACT")

    Logger().info("ticket:" + str(type(ticket)))

    assert isinstance(ticket, ContractTicket) == True

test_success_ticket works like a charm. However, when I try to run test_contract_ticket_soap(), it fails on an AssertionError, saying its a mock.
The error: test_call_ticket_lambda.py:93: AssertionError
The log: {"level":"INFO","location":"test_ticket_soap:91","message":"ticket:<class 'unittest.mock.Mock'>"}
It seems as though the @patch decorators are somehow extending beyond the test_success_ticket method. How is this possible? Is there some sort of teardown logic I need to run between each test case?

You're patching TicketFactory in the ticketfactory module but you're then importing TicketFactory from call_ticket_lambda. What's the relationship between ticketfactory and  call_ticket_lambda?

@blhsing the call_ticket_lambda imports ticketfactory and creates an instance of it within the lambda_handler
